# Replace Win 10 with Ubuntu completely

Tags: system-installation, 16.04, windows, uninstall

I've just bought a new Lenovo laptop with Win 10 preinstalled. I want to completely uninstall it and install Ubuntu or another Linux. I don't know yet what kind of protection it has from installing or removing windows, but I figure it's the latest one whatever it is. My question is, can I completely replace Win 10 with Ubuntu or another Linux and are there any difficulties?

update:

I've chosen another Linix distributes and created a bootable usb drive by using my another Linux machine:

```
dd bs=4M if=/my_linux.iso of=/dev/sdb status=progress && sync
```

And when I booted and chose "Boot from USB drive" with the name of my usb drive, nothing happened, it just hung for a few seconds and then returned back to the menu where I can choose the boot order.

Comment: You should be able to, by booting from an USB with Ubuntu installation. Lenovo usually doesn't have pre-installed limitations, but you can check in BIOS, open it as Lenovo logo appears by pressing F12 or F8.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can definitely do it:

1. Download the .iso of the Linux distro you desire.
2. Download the Universal USB installer.
3. Use the universal USB installer to create a bootable media, preferably a pen drive
4. Restart your PC and boot from the pendrive. You may need to go  into the BIOS and change boot device preference.
5. You will be guided through the installation procedure. It's quite informative and self explanatory.
6. Choose the correct set of options and if you face a doubt, feel free to ask.

Comment: look at my update.